Problem understanding the actual bandpass of my EEG signal
Greetings to all of the community members.
I am a clinical neurologist and in the last few weeks I am beginning to study EEG spectral analysis.
My unit uses CADWELL Essential 32 channels amplifier for EEG recording.
I know from the producer that the bandpass can be set as wide as 0.16 to 100 Hz. Specifically, I have been working with EEGs originally recorded with a 0.5-70 bandpass, 256 Hz sampling rate and notch filter ON.
I have always thought these recording settings to affect the actual recorded trace, so heavily cutting frequencies below 0.5 and above 70.
However, when I extract the full edf from the software and I analyse it with EEGLAB or EDFBrowser, the spectrum seems to contain the whole array of frequencies below 0.5 and above 70 without any true slope or filter effect. For instance, 50 Hz peak and its 100 Hz harmonic are dominant in the spectrum and the actual EEG is unreadable at its raw state, as if it were unfiltered at all. Only when I apply a digital filter the spectrum acquires the expected pattern and the EEG becomes readable.
My question is: are the filters that I set during the recording only active at the post-recording state (I.e. visual-display filter)? If not, and thus if they actually are active at the level of the recorded signal, why does the EDF contain all of the frequencies without true filter/notch effect?
Could this be due to low order HF and LF filters? Even in this case, I would not understand why frequencies well above 70 Hz are normally represented.
Does maybe my amplifier record with a "fixed" bandpass over which it applies the desired LF and HF after the signal has been acquired? Is my amplifier acquiring a fully unfiltered signal? What other problem may I be overlooking?
I sincerely apologise if I have said anything wrong, or if I asked a stupid question; I am new to signal analysis and possibly I need to build some basic knowledge, but I have not been able to solve this doubt by myself. I basically have no informatic/engineering skills.
I thank whoever will answer in advance.

If what you're pulling off of the machine with your signal viewer is definitely not what you've viewing when you're running the machine live -- yes, the filters are only being applied when viewing, not when capturing.
This is probably a good thing, especially if the machine records the raw data along with some metadata telling you what the filter settings were.  This would let you replicate what a clinician may have seen live, while still having data that you can view with different filtering options.
You can determine this experimentally by hooking up the machine to a convenient signal source (lab rat, grad student, yourself, whatever), snapping a picture of the screen, then looking at the recorded data with their viewer while applying filters to it.
If you need to apply filters to the recorded data to match your picture -- yes, absolutely, they're recording data that's been recorded raw (or at least that's been filtered differently).

Thank you so much! Fortunately I can give you direct feedback, as I was present during the recording. The screen showed these settings: HF 70 LF 0.5 notch ON. The EEG was clearly readable. This stands both during the recording and when I successively open the EEG for read on the same program (the one that comes with the machine where we make clinical EEG records after the recording). Things change when I download the EDF and open it in EEGLAB/EDFreader, where the signal is super noisy and I have to hard filter it to make it look like what I see on the EEG system programme.

In addition, when I open the metadata on EDFbrowser, the full exam notes and events are present but the "filter" screen is empty. All of these things might suggest that the settings displayed on the screen are not active at the recording level and correspond to post acquisition filters. My question now is, what are the true filters applied prior to signal storage by the amplifier, if any, or is the signal acquired totally unfiltered? Sorry for posting two separate comments but it was too long to fit in a single one

I can't answer your specific question about your specific machine, because I don't have any expertise with that machine.  As a next step, now that you know that at least some filtering seems to be done after the fact, I suggest contacting the manufacturer with your questions.
